# Postfix configuration troubleshoot

Tags: debian, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I have a mail server where I use Postfix and Dovecot. On this server I use ISPConfig for handling user mailboxes. I have now 2 main domains (mrtsolutions.it and geacloud.it).

I have 2 mailboxes: something@mrtsolutions.it and hello@geacloud.it

Using smtper.net I realized I can send email from something@mrtsolutions.it authenticating as hello@geacloud.it. I would like to send email only from account I used for the login.

I also realized that I can send email from something@mrtsolutions.it authenticating me on a completely different mail server such for example as my business company one (mail.vianova.it) using another account.

How can I solve? This scares me a lot.

This is my main.cf:
https://pastebin.com/NF39HZ1R

Answer (score 0):

With your own Postfix server you would need [`reject_sender_login_mismatch`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_sender_login_mismatch) which checks [`smtpd_sender_login_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps). Currently you have neither.

You can't handle which sender email addresses someone else's mail server accepts, but you can restrict the usage of your domains using SPF, DKIM and DMARC.